# BJT 2 stage amplifier

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, bjt

all I'm pretty new to electronics so my question may be a little ambiguous.

I have designed a two-stage amplifier using 2N3904's. the total ac gain should be over 5000. would this circuit do it? according to my calculations, it should work.

as far as the bypass caps, I have no idea on how to calculate them. 
any help will be appreciated.
[image: BJT Amplifier Circuit]

Comment: Make your capacitors large compared to their load (the resistances they are feeding into.) You can try \$C=\frac{100}{2\pi\:f\:R}\$, setting \$f\$ to the lowest frequency you care about and \$R\$ to a rough estimate of the "load" that it is feeding. So, for example, if \$f=200\:\text{Hz}\$ and \$R=2\:\text{k}\Omega\$, then you'd use \$C\approx 40\:\mu\text{F}\$. You do have to take a gander of some kind to see what surrounds the cap, though. But so long as you don't miss something important, you can get pretty close.

Comment: Show your computations for the gain. It would help a great deal in (1) seeing how you got to where you think you did, which saves the time of others in duplicating your work and (2) helps in allowing a shorter answer to make corrections, if needed.

Comment: If you use @jonk's method you have to consider the impedance looking into the emitter of the transistor, which dominates (you can actually ignore RE1/2).

Answer (score 2):

Each transistor runs near 5mA, thus reac ( 1/gm) is near 5 ohms. The collector resistors are each 1Kohm, thus maximum gain is 1,000 / 5 = 200.

Total maximum gain, ignoring Re of stage1, and the loading upon stage1 by stage2, etc, will be 200 * 200 = 40,000.

Now for the realities. Finite beta, assume 100, and the low reac of 5 ohms, tells us the Rin is at most 5 * 100 = 500. This is ignoring the biasing resistors. Gain drops by (500 || 1,000) / 1,000 =  0.333x. We are still ignoring the discrete Re1a of 3 ohms. Gain now has dropped by 67% in each stage,
thus total gain is 40,000 * 1/3 * 1/3 = 40,000/9 = 4,444x.

Now the non-zero Rsource, and the non-zero Re1a, get included in your gain.

By the way, given the 2nd order and 3rd order Intermodulation Intercepts for a bipolar (at any bias current, assuming non-saturated) are both near -10dBv (+- some dBv, but we'll approximate both wrongly as -10dBv), that -10dBv being a peak number used in a Taylor Series model of the emitter diode nonlinearity, and -10dBv is 0.316 volts, and given the 3rd order products drop 20 dBc for every 10dB dropoff from the Intercept Point (that -10dBv), to have 0.1% distortion which is 3 factors of 20dB you need to be 3*10dB below -10dBv IP3.

Thus for 0.1% distortion IM3, you need an input of about the size -10dBv IP - 3*10dB = -40dBv. Which is 0.01 volts input peak. Scaled by gain of 5,000, the output is 50 volts peak. Thus a whole nother world exists when you care about distortion.

Here is log-log plot of signal_in and signal_out levels, to illustrate distortion

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feXxFq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For any decent amplifier you will want the quiescent voltage at the collector of stage 1 to be about 50% of the supply rail (7.5 volts). This means that with a 1 kohm collector resistor you should design the collector current to be about 7.5 mA.

So, here's the first slight issue - you have 5.38 volts DC on the base and this sets the emitter at about 4.7 volts. This means emiiter current is about 4.7 mA and collector current is about the same. Not a show-stopper but not ideal.

So, collector current is 4.7 mA and this gives an \$r_E\$ of 26 mV/4.7 mA i.e. your internal emitter resistance will be about 5.6 ohms. Add this tou your external AC resistor (RE1A) of 3 ohms and the gain of the first stage is: -

RC1/8.6 ohms  = 1000/8.6 = 116.

However, the loading from the 2nd stage across RC1 will drop this somewhat. But how much loading?

Using the same calculation for \$r_E\$ we get the AC impedance at the emitter to be 5.6 ohms and this can be reflected to the base by transforming it by hFE. Looking at the DS of the 2N3904 I make an estimate of hFE being about 150 so, reflected \$r_E\$ is about 840 ohms.

This is the dominat impedance loading the collector of the first stage and reduces RC1 to an equivalent of 456 ohms.

This means that the gain of the first stage (with the 2nd stage connected and loading) is about 456/8.6 = 53.

For the 2nd stage, \$r_E\$ is 5.6 ohms and RC2 is 1,000 || 10,000 hence its gain is 909/5.6 = 162. Total gain is therefore 53 x 162 = 8604.

However, there will be significant distortion as the output signal level rises due to the non-linearities of relying on \$r_E\$ as a gain limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear and to protect from future edits to the question, here is the circuit you are asking about:

[image]

You want a gain of 5000, so at best that means a gain of 71 from each stage.  That is too much gain to expect a single-transistor stage to have.  You therefore should be expecting at least 3 stages.  If the gain is balanced between stages, that would mean a gain of 17 per stage.  That is more manageable, but still has problems.

Even with a gain of 17 per stage, the gain won't be all that well controlled.  A better way is to make more open loop gain, then use negative feedback to set the closed loop gain to what you really want.  The feedback ratio, which defines that closed loop gain, can be set by two resistors.  This allows good predictability and flat frequency response.

Another thing to consider is to use both NPN and PNP transistors together.  Transistors are cheap and small, so there is no reason to economize the number of transistors.  Using NPN and PNP together, even in the same stage, can have advantages of impedance, stage gain, and distortion.

If you just want something like a microphone amplifier and the result is more important than the journey, just use a couple of opamps.

However, to your specific circuit:

3 Ω for RE1A (Argh.  Just number them next time.)  is so low that it might as well not be there.  With only 3 Ω on the emitter, the non-linear effects of the B-E junction will dominate.  The approximation of constant B-E voltage is no longer valid.  You have to keep the capabilities of the transistors in mind.

You may think the gain of the first stage is RC1/RE1A, but it's not since RE1A is so absurdly low.  If the intent is to have a reasonably linear amplifier, don't try to get more than a gain of 20 out of a single stage like that.  A gain of 10 would be better, especially if there is no global negative feedback.

C1 will cause a high pass filter working against Rs.  Ignoring the additional input impedance of the first stage, that comes out to 265 Hz.  Is that what you intended?  If you care about lower frequencies, then you have to re-think C1

To be fair, the input impedance of the first stage adds to the effective resistance that C1 is working against, but that is rather unpredictable.  It's not going to be very high due to the very low RE1A.

C2 is 1000x larger than C1, although it is used in about the same situation.  What the...?

C4 and RE1B form a high pass rolloff of 1.6 Hz.  Make up your mind.

The second stage has no local AC feedback at all.  That makes its gain unpredictable and dependent on the particular transistor you happen to pick out of the box.  Note that gains of individual transistors can vary up to several times, even from the same production lot.

If you are looking for a linear amplifier result, such a stage is a bad idea, at least without global negative feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the high gain you want in two stages. To get to a gain of 5000, you need \$\sqrt{5000}\approx 71\$ per stage. That's doable.

Let's start with some specifications. Because of the high gain, I'm going to require a \$15\:\text{V}\$ power supply in order to keep this simple and easy. To get lots of gain from each stage, I am going to estimate a quiescent collector voltage around \$7\:\text{V}\$. The unloaded gain is \$A_v=\frac{V_\text{CC}-V_\text{C}}{V_\text{T}}\approx 300\$. The second stage will very significantly load down the first stage, though. (I'm assuming you use a low impedance signal generator for the first stage and that you do not significantly load the second stage.)

I'll reserve about \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ as the minimum collector voltage to provide some headroom for \$V_\text{CE}\$ and \$V_\text{E}\$. This means I'm limited on the last stage to about \$\pm 4\:\text{V}\$ of swing.

I'll use the exact same stage twice. So let's just design the last stage first, since we know what the output quiescent point and swing needs to be there. Here's the basic concept:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUXZMbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm going to select \$I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=5\:\text{mA}\$ as a starting point. This means \$r_e= \frac{V_\text{T}}{I_\text{C}}\approx 5\:\Omega\$.

$$\begin{align*}R_\text{C}&=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{15\:\text{V}-7\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{mA}}&=1600\:\Omega\\\text{standard value}&=1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\end{array}\right.\\R_\text{E}&=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1.5\:\text{V}}{15\:\text{V}-7\:\text{V}}\cdot 1.5\:\text{k}\Omega &=280\:\Omega\\\text{standard value}&=270\:\Omega\end{array}\right.\\C_\text{2}&=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot\left(f=1\:\text{kHz}\right)\cdot 10\%\:r_e} &=320\:\mu\text{F}\\\text{standard value}&=270\:\mu\text{F}\end{array}\right.\end{align*}$$

(Here you can see how I might estimate the value of the capacitor. I used about 10% of the value of \$r_e\$ at the lowest frequency of interest. Bigger in this case wouldn't hurt. But there's already going to be more gain than you need. So I'm leaving it as is.)

From this, I can now estimate \$V_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}=\left(15\:\text{V}-7\:\text{V}\right)\cdot\frac{R_\text{E}}{R_\text{C}}=1.44\:\text{V}\$ and add \$700\:\text{mV}\$ to get about \$V_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}\approx 2.2\:\text{V}\$. I'm going to shoot for about \$400\:\mu\text{A}\$ as the divider current. This means:

$$\begin{align*}R_\text{1}&=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{15\:\text{V}-2.2\:\text{V}}{400\:\mu\text{A}}&=32\:\text{k}\Omega\\\text{standard value}&=33\:\text{k}\Omega\end{array}\right.\\
R_\text{2}&=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{2.2\:\text{V}}{400\:\mu\text{A}-33\:\mu\text{A}} &=6\:\text{k}\Omega\\\text{standard value}&=5.6\:\text{k}\Omega\end{array}\right.\end{align*}$$

Now let's stick two of these together:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb2thE.png)</sup>

The first stage will load your source, probably cutting the signal in half. The second stage is going to load the first stage quite a bit, too. I wouldn't be surprised to see a factor of 3 lost. A total gain here of perhaps \$\frac{1}{2}\cdot 250\cdot 250\cdot\frac{1}{3}\approx 10,000\$. That's more than you need. (Gain on the first stage shouldn't vary a lot as the signal moves up and down, because the signal is still small there. But the second stage might be just a little asymmetrical. But probably you won't notice.)

Don't feed it a signal larger than about \$50\:\mu\text{V}\$, to start. See where that takes the output before trying anything more.